# How to find the list of parameter lambda used in the Box-Cox transformations in R

Tags: r, lambda, statistics

Given a dataset X, How to find the list of parameters of **lambda** used in Box-Cox transformations.

```
x1 = c(1,2,0,5,1,4,2,6,2,0)
x2 = c(3,2,5,6,5,1,2,1,4,4)
x3 = c(4,0,1,3,2,4,5,3,1,0)

X = cbind(x1,x2,x3)
```

Comment: boxcox doesn't work on data with 0's in it. All data must >0.
Using `library(bestNormalize)` because I am familiar with it. 
`boxcox(x1)` produces: Error in estimate_boxcox_lambda(x, ...) : x must be positive

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get rid of the 0's in your data, or there are none in your real data (See comment I made after your Question. Here I have changed 0 to 0.0001 for convenience), then this should work:

```
library(bestNormalize)

x1 = c(1,2,0.0001,5,1,4,2,6,2,0.0001)
x2 = c(3,2,5,6,5,1,2,1,4,4)
x3 = c(4,0.0001,1,3,2,4,5,3,1,0.0001)

X = cbind(x1,x2,x3)

temp <- apply(X, 2, boxcox)

listLambda <- lapply(temp, "[[" , "lambda")
listLambda

listBCconverted <- lapply(temp, "[[", "x.t")
listBCconverted
```

Note: boxcox here has standardised the transformation around mean value 0.